# Error while Deserializing the XML string into object type

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, web-services, asp.net-web-api, c#-4.0

I am consuming a third party web service in our application in the SOAP XML format. The response what we are getting is in XML format also. While deserializing the XML string to object type we are getting "There is an error in XML document (1, 5584). I have checked the XML also before deserializing it looks perfect for me in the mentioned position. Can anyone tell what is the issue here?

```
            HttpWebRequest request = CreateWebRequest("GetEmploymentVerificationFields");
            XmlDocument soapEnvelopeXml = new XmlDocument();

            var loadXML = @"<?xml version=""1.0"" encoding=""utf-8""?><soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv=""http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"" xmlns:v29=""https://e-verify.uscis.gov/WebService/EmployerService/V29""><soapenv:Header><wsse:Security soapenv:mustUnderstand=""1"" xmlns:wsse=""http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd"" xmlns:wsu=""http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd""><wsse:UsernameToken wsu:Id=""UsernameToken-BEC9D84D8B68A3118D14543420311491""><wsse:Username></wsse:Username><wsse:Password></wsse:Password><wsse:Nonce EncodingType=""http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-soap-message-security-1.0#Base64Binary"">hBcjVXk/NxiSiva5xXKphA==</wsse:Nonce><wsu:Created>2017-10-10T12:40:11.947Z</wsu:Created></wsse:UsernameToken></wsse:Security></soapenv:Header><soapenv:Body><GetEmploymentVerificationFields xmlns=""https://e-verify.uscis.gov/WebService/EmployerService/V29""><request xmlns:b=""https://e-verify.uscis.gov/WebService/EmployerService/V29/"" xmlns:i=""http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance""><b:CitizenshipStatusCode i:nil=""true"">";
            loadXML += model.CitizenshipStatusCode + @"</b:CitizenshipStatusCode><b:DocumentTypeId i:nil=""true"">";
            loadXML += model.DocumentTypeId + @"</b:DocumentTypeId><b:ListBDocumentTypeId i:nil=""true"">";
            loadXML += model.ListBDocumentTypeId + @"</b:ListBDocumentTypeId><b:SupportingDocumentTypeId i:nil=""true"">";
            loadXML += model.SupportingDocumentTypeId + @"</b:SupportingDocumentTypeId><b:IssuingAuthorityCode i:nil=""true"">";
            loadXML += model.IssuingAuthorityCode + "</b:IssuingAuthorityCode></request></GetEmploymentVerificationFields></soapenv:Body></soapenv:Envelope>";

            soapEnvelopeXml.LoadXml(loadXML);

            using (Stream stream = request.GetRequestStream())
            {
                soapEnvelopeXml.Save(stream);
            }

            using (WebResponse response = request.GetResponse())
            {
                using (StreamReader rd = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()))
                {
                    string soapResult = rd.ReadToEnd();
                    soapResult = soapResult.Replace("xmlns=\"https://e-verify.uscis.gov/WebService/EmployerService/V29\"", "");
                    soapResult = soapResult.Replace("xmlns:a=\"https://e-verify.uscis.gov/WebService/EmployerService/V29/\"", "");
                    soapResult = soapResult.Replace("xmlns:i=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\"", "");
                    soapResult = soapResult.Replace("a:", "");
                    soapResult = soapResult.Replace("i:nil=\"true\"", "");

                    var firstIndex = soapResult.IndexOf("GetEmploymentVerificationFieldsResult");
                    var lastIndex = soapResult.LastIndexOf("GetEmploymentVerificationFieldsResult");
                    var count = "GetEmploymentVerificationFieldsResult".Length + 2;
                    var data = soapResult.Substring(firstIndex - 1, (lastIndex - firstIndex) + count);

                    XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(GetEmploymentVerificationFieldsResult));
                    using (TextReader reader = new StringReader(data))
                    {
                        GetEmploymentVerificationFieldsResult result = (GetEmploymentVerificationFieldsResult)serializer.Deserialize(reader);
                        return result;
                    }
                }
            }
```

Comment: The XML which is generated in data is as follows:

Comment: I would take a copy of the xml in `soapResult` as well as the copy after your string manipulation and save them both to separate files.  Then using a formatter (either online or through an IDE) to 'beautify' the code so you can compare the lines.  You can then either compare the files with a tool (winmerge?) or, if you open the files in a browser, the browser parser will tell you if there's an error with the structure.

Comment: This seems like a very manual and laborious way to do it. Is there a reason you can't use the WSDL for the target service and let Visual Studio or [wsdl.exe](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7h3ystb6(v=vs.90).aspx) generate you a proxy class that would do all this heaving lifting for you?